# How can I include HTML entities in my Angular2 application?

Tags: angular, html-entities, angular-cli

I'm using Angular-CLI to build a simple style guide app. It's choking on cases where I have preformatted HTML markup that includes HTML entities:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Unknown entity "rdqo" - use the "&#<decimal>;" or  "&#x<hex>;" syntax ("
>
> <pre><code>
>     &ldquo; [ERROR ->]&rdqo; (“ ”)
>     &ldsuo; &rsqo; (‘ ’
>     &mdash; (—)
> "): TypographyComponent@15:12
> ```

My component markup looks like this:

```
<pre><code>
    &ldquo; &rdqo; (“ ”)
    &ldsuo; &rsqo; (‘ ’)
    &mdash; (—)
    &hellip; (…)
</code></pre>
```

How can I include or escape such markup in preformatted blocks in a way that Angular-CLI will tolerate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code and got the same parsing errors. The problem is that you have misspelled some HTML entities - if you use the following instead:

```
<pre><code>
    &ldquo; &rdquo; (“ ”)
    &lsquo; &rsquo; (‘ ’)
    &mdash; (—)
    &hellip; (…)
</code></pre>
```

Then it works fine for me. That is:

&rdqo should be &rdquo

&ldsuo should be &lsquo

&rsqo should be &rsquo

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use **ngNonBindable**?

```
<pre ngNonBindable>
    <code>
    &ldquo; &rdqo; (“ ”)
    &ldsuo; &rsqo; (‘ ’)
    &mdash; (—)
    &hellip; (…)
    </code>
</pre>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable